# Movie where person is buried in coins?

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only thing I remember about the movie is that there is a scene where a person is placed in a small chamber of plastic or glass, and, in the classic movie villain style, is given his multi million dollar payment all in small change and is then buried.

Comment: :) Just because someone is bound to ask, are you fairly certain this is a science fiction or fantasy film?

Comment: I don't remember much about it, but it was either science fiction or action. It definitely was not fantasy. The clothing on the people (I remember bizarre details) points toward science fiction and bars fantasy.

Comment: There was a billionaire duck in the movie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you have misremembered a scene from a book as being from a movie? Exactly what you describe happens to a character called Charlie Roper in *Eagle Strike*, the fourth book in the [*Alex Rider*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Rider) series by Anthony Horowitz about a teenage spy. Here is a [quote](https://alexrider.wikia.com/wiki/Charlie_Roper) from the *Alex Rider* Wikia:

> Roper worked for the NSA and supplied Damian Cray with the codes to
>   detonate the American nuclear missiles (as part of Cray's master
>   plan). He was also bribed by Cray to deliver critical information, but
>   he was careless in doing so and attracted the attention of a
>   journalist named Edward Pleasure, Sabina Pleasure's father. He found
>   out about Roper's gambling habit and followed him, and Cray found out
>   about this and regarded Roper as a traitor.[1](https://alexrider.wikia.com/wiki/Charlie_Roper)
>
> In response, Cray locked Roper in a bottle-shaped room and paid Roper
>   two million dollars for his work - in quarters. The coins poured down
>   on top of Roper from a hole at the top of the chamber, and Roper was
>   unable to escape. He was quickly buried alive under the huge mass of
>   coins and was crushed by their weight.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Rider)

But it's a book, not a film. So far as I know there is no scene of a man getting buried by coins in the [film of *Stormbreaker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormbreaker_(film)), the first book in the series, and no further Alex Rider films were made.

Comment: That's definitely it. Thank you. I do tend to have a vivid imagination for books

Comment: As a side notice, I seem to remember that ending up buried in coins was one of the possible "bad endings" you could get in the videogame "Shadows of Chernobyl".